# Vue3 Route Transition not work on all pages and after refresh page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I have problem with implementing transitions route when page is changed. Am using VUE 3 and have implemented Single Page App.

1. When am on Home page that not work.
2. When i change page to AboutUs and refresh transitions work.
3. When i go to Contact page from About us work.
4. When i back from contact to Home not work.
5. When am on home and do refresh not work.

*So on all work except on '/' homepage.*

I implement it in **Root Component**

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
     <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
            <component :is="Component" />
     </transition>
</router-view>
```

**style.css**

```
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Here is full code:

```
<script>
    import HeaderTop from './pages/partials/header_top.vue'
    import HeaderMiddle from './pages/partials/header_middle.vue'
    import MainNavbar from './pages/partials/main_navbar.vue'
    import MainFooter from './pages/partials/footer.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            HeaderTop,
            HeaderMiddle,
            MainNavbar,
            MainFooter
        }

       
    }
</script>
<template>
    <!-- Header start -->
    <header class="header_wrap">
        <div class="header-top">
            <HeaderTop></HeaderTop>
        </div>
        <div class="header-middle">
            <HeaderMiddle></HeaderMiddle>
        </div>
        <div class="header-bottom">
            <MainNavbar></MainNavbar>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Header end -->

    <!-- Content start -->
    <main role="main">
     
        <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
            <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
                <component :is="Component" />
            </transition>
        </router-view>

    </main>
    <!-- Content end -->

    <!-- Footer start -->
    <footer id="main-footer">
        <MainFooter></MainFooter>
    </footer>
    <!-- Footer end -->
</template>
```

Comment: `When am on Home page that not work.` ... you mean, when you first load? because if you're "on Home page" there is no navigation to transition :p

Comment: other than the fact that I use `<Transition` (note: the capital T) - I can't see any issue - I mean, if the capital T is the issue, then you'd never get a transition

Comment: Of first load on '/' home and on other pages not work. When i change to another page and refresh than work. And when i visit all other work execpt on home. I also put T capital but nothing. I cant upload gif to see

Comment: I don't need a GIF, your question explains the issue adequately - does this happen (or not happen) in every browser, or is it just chrome (I'm guessing you use crhome)

Comment: I test in chrome, firefox and safari. All the some!

Comment: Are you at all proficient at using `codesandbox.io` or similar? having code that demonstrates the issue would possibly help - you can bootstrap a vue instance on codesandbox.io by going to `https://vue.new`

Comment: Can you modify this codesandbox and describe whats not working ?https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-sea-ev4uxi